# Problem with CSS on display of elements

Tags: html, css

`<p style="float: left; position: relative; left: 130px; top: 80px; display: none;" id="homehref"><a href="" style="color: white;">Home Page</a></p>`

I have this as my hidden element on the header of my site.

Whenever i mouseover over the header logo i show this element.

In firefox its working fine. But in IE 7 it shifts navigation below it. Can somebody suggest how i can keep my Home Page link truly floating in ie7 as well.

Comment: please show us the complete code (the header, too) and your css - otherwise it's almost impossible to tell whats wrong.

Comment: @sushil , is there any reason why you are using "p" instead of a div

Comment: Can somebody please tell me generally as to how to make a element float on a page. So that there is no effect on element below it. I mean it can move over a layer above. I cant bring the entire code here.

Comment: no there isnt a reason i have replaced p with a div. But there isnt any effect. Any small hint will be a big help.

Comment: if you want to float some element over another you can give negative margin like margin-top:-20px; , so that it will come on top of other element , other option will be absolute positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
#divtofloat{
position : absolute
top:10px;
left:10px
}
```

its stays 10px from left and 10px from top of the page. if you want to come over another element you can give z-index higher than the elements on the page.

With absolute positioning , you can place the div anywhere on the page ...with top,left ,bottom properties.

Answer (score 0):

The floating works depending on the container-content relationship, so I need to know how html is structured. Anyhow, doesn't seem floating is best solution here. Besides, you have to separate structure (html) from presentation (css). You may need:
HTML:

```
<div id="header">
   <a href="link_to_home">
      <img src="logo_url" />
      <span class="tooltip">Home Page</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header a { position: relative;}
#header a span { display: none; position: absolute; left:130px; top: 80px; }
#header a:hover span { display: block;}
```

How's it working now?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your fully source code but I think you would like to do tooltip on your header logo.If whatever you do [here](http://www.designzzz.com/jquery-css-tooltip-tutorials/) is jquery tooltip would cool style.

Answer (score 0):

@sushi, you could make test page and put it somewhere, then show us :|

Anyway, we're all a little blind here without actual code of situation, but I can assume that maybe you need to put in markup float:left element above over header elements, or use overflow:hidden on it, or somth.

But as @gov already proposed earlier, maybe it's easier to make it absolute positioned. Don't forget to make header element positioned relative in that case.